# Scrolling problems when using ScaleTransform in Panorama/Pivot/RadSlideView item

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, telerik, panorama-control, rendertransform

I'm trying to implement zoom-functionality in a RadSlideView ItemTemplate. I'm doing this by using a ViewportControl with a Canvas and then applying a RenderTransform (ScaleTransform) to a StackPanel in the Canvas. Similar to the SDK-sample found [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Image-Recipes-0c0b8fee).

The problem I have is that the ScaleTransform seems to be affecting the swipe-gesture used to change item in the SlideView/Panorama/Pivot control. E.g. if the ScaleTransform is set to 0.1 it seems like I only need to swipe 1/10th of the length to change item compared to using a ScaleTransform of 1.0.

I found that if I set `IsHitTestVisible` to false on the ItemTemplate the swiping works like I want. But this is not a solution since I sometimes need to be able to pan the content vertically while still being able to change item by swiping horizontally.

So my question is how can I solve this?

For reference the XAML looks like this:

```
<Controls:RadSlideView Name="SlideView" ItemsSource="{Binding Pages}" IsLoopingEnabled="False" SelectionChanged="RadSlideView_SelectionChanged" CacheMode="BitmapCache" ManipulationStarted="SlideView_ManipulationStarted" ManipulationCompleted="SlideView_ManipulationCompleted" ManipulationDelta="SlideView_ManipulationDelta">
<Controls:RadSlideView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ViewportControl x:Name="SlideViewViewport" ViewportChanged="SlideViewViewport_ViewportChanged" Loaded="SlideViewViewport_Loaded">
            <Canvas>
                <StackPanel>
                    <Image Source="{Binding Image}" Stretch="Fill" Width="{Binding ElementName=SlideView, Path=DataContext.PageWidth}" Height="{Binding ElementName=SlideView, Path=DataContext.PageHeight}" CacheMode="BitmapCache"/>
                    <StackPanel.RenderTransform>
                        <ScaleTransform x:Name="xform"/>
                    </StackPanel.RenderTransform>
                </StackPanel>
            </Canvas>
        </ViewportControl>
    </DataTemplate>
</Controls:RadSlideView.ItemTemplate>
```

I have also looked at Teleriks RadPanAndZoom-control to avoid implementing my own zoom-functionality, but since I sometimes need to place two pictures side by side and zoom them as if they were one I don't think I can use it.

Comment: Have you tried using two RadPanAndZoom? and keep their zoom levels synced?

Comment: I have played around a bit with it but I don't see how it could work. I need the images to be zoom-able and pan-able as if it was one image. So the right border of the left image is at the left border of the right image, I don't think this is possible using two RadPanAndZoom controls with synced zoom levels.

Comment: What is it you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that ScaleTransformation scales your picture, but doesn't change it's height and width. Only if Height And Width are overflowing scrollviewer you can scroll the content